# Output folder/file name of the current folder/file to be copied

Tags: bash, copy

I wan't to copy a specific folder structure containing files and folders and have an output that tells the user how far the copying is.

Currently I use the following to copy the structure whithout some specific folders:

```
cp -rfv !(Project.buildoutput) $Project_SYNC_DIR
```

But the `cp -v` output is very ugly:

```
> _55_studio.tests/singles/CustomIdentifier.file -> /Users/<path>/_55_studio.tests/singles/CustomIdentifier.file build.sh
> -> /Users/<path>/build.sh
```

Is it possible to output only the Level 1 elements with a clean name.

My current folder structure:

```
_55_studio
--singles
--mixed
_55_studio.tests
--singles
build.sh
project.settings
```

output to following while copying:

```
Copy folder _55_studio
Copy folder _55_studio.tests
Copy file build.sh
Copy file project.settings
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this and how?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in a one-liner using `find`:

```
find "/path/to/dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "Project.buildoutput" -prune -o -exec /bin/bash -c "echo -en \"Copy \"; \
                                                                                                      [ -d '{}' ] && echo -en \"folder \";\
                                                                                                      [ -f '{}' ] && echo -en \"file \"; \
                                                                                                      basename '{}'; \
                                                                                                      cp -fr '{}' \"$Project_SYNC_DIR\"" \;
```

Output:

```
Copy folder _55_studio
Copy folder _55_studio.tests
Copy file build.sh
Copy file project.settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1, extract directories:

```
sed -e 's#^\([^/]\+\) -> .*$#\1#g' -e 's#^\([^/]\+\)/.*$#\1#g'
```

The first replace, replaces lines like this:

```
`file_name' -> `path/to/copy/file_name'
```

to:

```
file_name
```

And the second replace, replaces lines like this:

```
`path/to/file' -> `other/path/to/copy/file'
```

to:

```
path
```

Note that I added ` and ' because my cp adds them.

Step 2, remove duplicates:

```
uniq
```

Step 3, check to see if it's a file or directory:

```
while read f; do \
  if [ -d $f ]; then \
    echo Copy folder $f \
  else \
     echo Copy file $f \
  fi \
done
```

Therefore:

```
cp -rfv !(Project.buildoutput) $Project_SYNC_DIR | \
  sed -e 's#^`\([^/]\+\)'"'"' -> .*$#\1#g' \
      -e 's#^`\([^/]\+\)/.*$#\1#g' | \
  uniq | \
  while read f; do \
    if [ -d $f ]; then \
      echo Copy folder $f; \
    else \
      echo Copy file $f; \
    fi \
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to get very close to what you asked:

```
for src in !(Project.buildoutput); do 
    stat -c "Copy %-14F %n" "${src}"; cp -rf "$src" $Project_SYNC_DIR; done
```

(Need `shopt -s extglob` for extended globbing: ! to invert match)

Or to show every file/directory

```
unbuffer cp -rfv !(Project.buildoutput) $Project_SYNC_DIR | 
    while read src dd dst; do stat -c "Copy %-14F %n" "$src"; done
```

GNU `stat` used above, for *BSD use `stat -f "Copy %-14SHT %N"` instead.

My (GNU coreutils 6.9) `cp -v` insists on printing broken quotes in the output, a quick hack to work with the above is to add a `tr` to the pipeline:

```
...  | tr -d \`\' | while ...
```

If you have spaces or single-quotes in your file/directory names something more elaborate will be required.

If you like perl to do your heavy lifting (and deal with `' quoting);

```
... | perl -ne $'/\`(.*)\' -> \`(.*)\'/ && 
  printf("Copy %-14s %s\n",(-f $1 ? "file" : -d $1 ? "directory" : "<other>"),$1);'
```

This should be more efficient if you have many files, because only one extra process is needed, not one per file/directory copied.

The common solution for more feedback during copy is to use `rsync` instead:

```
rsync --progress -hrv src/ dest/
```

`rsync` is more efficient than `cp`, it doesn't copy files it doesn't need to, add "`-W`" to force a copy like `cp`.